# how to pass a string into a pipe and print the response using process builder

Tags: java, stream, pipe

here is some code I'm trying to get working. Basically I need to keep the process open, and feed it new commands in a single session. Once the "exit" string command is issued the process should finish. Appreciate help....

```
Process process;
ArrayList<String>command;
ProcessBuilder builder;
Map<String, String> environ;
BufferedWriter bw;
BufferedReader br;
BufferedReader buffErrorStreamReader;

....

 try
    {
    command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("cmd.exe");
    command.add("/c");
    //command.add(currentLine);

    builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    environ = builder.environment();

    builder.directory(new File("C://"));
    process = builder.start();

    }catch(Exception e)
          {
          System.out.println(e);
          }

    //Get a System.in Stream
    OutputStream output = process.getOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(output);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

    //Get a System.out Stream
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    //Get a System.err Stream
    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader errorStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);
    buffErrorStreamReader = new BufferedReader(errorStreamReader);



....

//Read the command from my text component terminal
String currentLine = getCurrentLine();


    ///pass command to pipe input 
    bw.write(currentLine);
    System.out.println("wrote: "+currentLine);

    ///print response 
     String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      System.out.println(line);
      //term.println(line);    
    }

    ///print any error response
    String errorLine;
    while ((errorLine = buffErrorStreamReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      System.out.println(errorLine);
      //term.println(errorLine);    
    }
```

Comment: Please update question with more details. How does your code not work? Hangs? Throws exception? Is the problem in getting process to start, or writing to it, or it receiving, or it sending the response, or reading the response?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading both the error stream and the input stream until EOS, which won't happen until the process exits (or, so rarely that I've never seen it in 30+ years, closes stdout and stderr). The usual practice is to (a) merge the error and output streams and/or (b) read it/them in separate threads, so that in this case you can keep feeding input from its source without having to bother with the resulting output if any, which in the nature of things you can't know too much about in an external process.

Answer (score 0):

My full code is working. I have a terminal that takes a command from the current line on a canvas. Then it assembles a process builder with: "cmd.exe", "/c" and "the command string from the current line" parameters. Finally it gets the builder environment and sets the builder directory. It then starts the process and gets both Input and Error Streams for the process. Then it prints these responses to my canvas terminal. However, the problem with my approach is that I am opening a new cmd.exe (dos command prompt) with every process. So basically, its a non interactive terminal because there is no session established between command submissions (new processes). The process just takes the command, prints the output and terminates each time. So my question is how can I implement an interactive terminal session. I have successfully implemented the ability to change directories by saving the current path and passing it to the new process with the builder.directory method. Also it may be possible to do the same thing for environment var's with the builder.environment (but I cant figure that out). That would give the impression of a real session. I have also tried the threading for the streams and it does work. But I must be doing it wrong as the process terminates after the thread prints the command response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for my Terminal, in two pieces. The code im talking about is located in the switch statement for the VK.ENTER key.

NB. If you are changing directories it will only work with absoulute paths. Eg "cd C://Users/Aubrey/" not "cd /Aubrey" in the Users directory!!!

```
/*
 * Terminal.java - A convienence console.
 * 
 * http://www.splashportal.net
 * 30/09/2012
 */
package terminal;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class Terminal extends Canvas
{
static final long serialVersionUID = 5479170142892558288L;

public static int WIDTH = 80, HEIGHT = 200;
static Process process;

public static final Color
    WHITE       = new Color(0xffffff),
    RED         = new Color(0xff0000),
    GREEN       = new Color(0x00cc00),
    BROWN       = new Color(0x996600),
    BLUE        = new Color(0x0000ff),
    DARK_GREEN  = new Color(0x009900),
    DARK_BLUE   = new Color(0x000099),
    LIGHT_GREY  = new Color(0x999999),
    DARK_GREY   = new Color(0x666666),
    CYAN        = new Color(0x00ffff),
    DARK_CYAN   = new Color(0x009999),
    DARK_YELLOW = new Color(0x999900),
    MAGENTA     = new Color(0xff00ff),
    YELLOW      = new Color(0xffff00),
    PURPLE      = new Color(0x990099),
    BLACK       = new Color(0x000000);

private static final Color[] COLORS = {
        WHITE           ,  // 0 @
        RED             ,  // 1 A
        GREEN           ,  // 2 B
        BROWN           ,  // 3 C
        BLUE            ,  // 4 D
        DARK_GREEN      ,  // 5 E
        DARK_BLUE       ,  // 6 F
        LIGHT_GREY      ,  // 7 G
        DARK_GREY       ,  // 8 H
        CYAN            ,  // 9 I
        DARK_CYAN       ,  // 10 J
        DARK_YELLOW     ,  // 11 K
        MAGENTA         ,  // 12 L
        YELLOW          ,  // 13 M
        PURPLE          ,  // 14 N
        BLACK           ,  // 15 O
    };

public static final int EFFECTS_UNDERLINE = 1;

private static final int
    ESC_NORMAL  = 0,
    ESC_ESCAPE  = 1,
    ESC_POS_Y   = 2,
    ESC_POS_X   = 3,
    ESC_FGCOLOR = 4,
    ESC_BGCOLOR = 5;

    static boolean isBreak=false;
    static int heightCounter;
    static ArrayList lines;
    static Terminal term;
    static Frame f;
    static File startPath;

public static Color getColor(int i)
{
    return COLORS[i & 0x0f];
}
static String newPath = System.getenv("temp");


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    f = new Frame("Terminal Test");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                f.dispose();
            }
        } );

    term = new Terminal();

     //add buffer_ image to a scrollpane somehow?
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

    scrollPane.add(term, buffer_);

    // disabling forward focus traversal allows TAB to reach the component
    term.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
            Collections.EMPTY_SET);
    term.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                // handle special keys
                switch(ke.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                        term.print("\033A");
                        term.repaint();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                        term.print("\033B");
                        term.repaint();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        term.print("\033C");
                        term.repaint();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        term.print("\033D");
                        term.repaint();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:

    //flag set to block printing of ">>" prompt                 
    isR=true;                    
    try{
    String currentLine = getCurrentLine();
    ArrayList<String>command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("cmd.exe");
    command.add("/c");
    command.add(currentLine);
    System.out.println("Line-IN: "+currentLine);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();

    if (currentLine.startsWith("cd")){      
    //startPath = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile();    

    //if an absolute path is specified and exists    
    if(new File(currentLine.substring(3)).exists())
    newPath=currentLine.substring(3);

    System.out.println("Directory : "+new File(newPath));
    builder.directory(new File(newPath));
    process = builder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader errorStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);
    BufferedReader buffErrorStreamReader = new BufferedReader(errorStreamReader);

    String line;
    //term.println("");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
      term.println(line);    
    }
    String errorLine;
    term.println("");
    while ((errorLine = buffErrorStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
      //System.out.println(line);
      term.println(errorLine);    
    }
    buffErrorStreamReader.close();
    br.close();
    //not sure how to use this method to allow for an interactive prompt?
    //for example a "dir /p" command should allow the output to be paged per keypress!
    process.waitFor();
    //flags set to allow printing of ">>" prompt
    isR=false;
    isNew=true;

    System.out.println("Program terminated!");

    }else if(currentLine.startsWith("exit")||currentLine.startsWith("quit")){
                               System.exit(0);
    }else if(currentLine.startsWith("dir /p")){
        //try using dos batch?
    System.out.println("page...");
    command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("cmd.exe");
    command.add("dir"); 
    builder.directory(new File(newPath));
    process = builder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line;

    //write out to a FLAT FILE.
    File temp = new File("temp");
    PrintWriter tempOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    tempOut.println(line);    
    }
    //not sure how to use this method to allow for an interactive prompt?
    //for example a "dir /p" command should allow the output to be paged per keypress!
    process.waitFor();

    //flags set to allow printing of ">>" prompt

    br.close();
    tempOut.flush();
    tempOut.close();

    captureLines();  
    int index = 0;

    printPage(index);

    isR=false;
    isNew=true;

    System.out.println("Program terminated!");


    }else
    {    


    builder.directory(new File(newPath));
    process = builder.start();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try{
        System.out.println("blah");
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader errorStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);
    BufferedReader buffErrorStreamReader = new BufferedReader(errorStreamReader);



    String line;
    //term.println("");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      //System.out.println(line);
      term.println(line);    
    }
    String errorLine;
    //term.println("");
    while ((errorLine = buffErrorStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
      //System.out.println(line);
      term.println(errorLine);    
    }
    buffErrorStreamReader.close();
    br.close();
    //not sure how to use this method to allow for an interactive prompt?
    //for example a "dir /p" command should allow the output to be paged per keypress!
    process.waitFor();

   //flags set to allow printing of ">>" prompt
    isR=false;
    isNew=true;  

    term.println("");
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
};
t.start();




    System.out.println("Program terminated!");
} 

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  }
}

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
                char c = ke.getKeyChar();
                if( c == KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED ) {
                    // handle special keys
                    switch(ke.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_TAB:
                            c = '\t';
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                            c = (char)27;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if( c != KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED ) {
                    term.print(c);
                    term.repaint();
                }
            }
        } );

    f.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    term.validate();
    scrollPane.setSize(598, 316);
    //f.setSize(700, 400);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    term.println(DARK_GREY, WHITE, "vTerminal");
    //term.println(DARK_GREY, WHITE, ">>");
    term.requestFocus();
}

private int tileWidth_ = 8;
private int tileHeight_ = 12;
private static TerminalLine[] line_;
private int xCursor_;
private static int yCursor_;
private int xCursorSave_;
private int yCursorSave_;
private boolean wrap_ = true;
private boolean scroll_ = true;
private boolean cursorVisible_ = true;
private int tab_ = 8;
private int xOffset_ = 0;
private int yOffset_ = 0;
private int escapeMode_ = ESC_NORMAL;
/** First character held in an ESC Y Position Cursor command. */
private int escapeHold_ = -1;
private boolean reverseVideo_;
private byte effects_;

private static Image buffer_;
private static ScrollPane scrollPane;
private static Boolean isNew = false;
private static Boolean isR = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

//second part to the working code

```
/** Creates a new terminal.  */
    public Terminal()
    {



        line_ = new TerminalLine[HEIGHT];
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
            line_[y] = new TerminalLine(WIDTH);
        }

        setBackground(DARK_GREY);
        setForeground(LIGHT_GREY);
        setFont( new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12) );
        clearScreen();
    }
    public static void captureLines(){

        String line;

        try{

        heightCounter=Terminal.HEIGHT;
        BufferedReader tempIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp"));
        term.println("");
        lines = new ArrayList();
        while((line = tempIn.readLine())!=null)
            {
            lines.add(line);
            }
        tempIn.close();

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        return;
    }
    public static void printPage(int index){
        try{
        if(index<lines.size()){
        for (int i=0; i<25; i++){

            if(index==lines.size())
              return; 

           //System.out.println(index+" "+lines.get(index));
           term.println(lines.get(index).toString());
           index++;  
        }Thread.sleep(500);

        printPage(index);
        }else{return;}

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }

    public static String getCurrentLine(){
    TerminalLine currentLine = line_[getYCursor()];
        String command="";

                for(char c: currentLine.data){
                command+= c;
                        }
        String outString = command.substring(2);
        return (outString.trim());
    }

    public synchronized void clearScreen()
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
            clearLine(y);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public synchronized void clearLine(int line)
    {
        clearLine(line, 0, WIDTH-1);
    }

    public synchronized void clearLine(int y, int x0, int x1)
    {
        Color bg = getBackground();
        Color fg = getForeground();
        TerminalLine line = line_[y];


        for(int x = x0; x <= x1; ++x) {
            line.data[x] = ' ';
            line.bgColor[x] = bg;
            line.fgColor[x] = fg;
            line.effects[x] = 0;
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean getCursorVisible()
    { return cursorVisible_; }

    public synchronized char getData(int x, int y)
    {
        return line_[y].data[x];
    }

    public synchronized Color getBgColor(int x, int y)
    {
        return line_[y].bgColor[x];
    }

    public synchronized byte getEffects(int x, int y)
    {
        return line_[y].effects[x];
    }

    public synchronized Color getFgColor(int x, int y)
    {
        return line_[y].fgColor[x];
    }

    public synchronized Dimension getMaximumSize()
    {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public synchronized Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public synchronized Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH * tileWidth_, HEIGHT * tileHeight_);
    }

    public boolean getReverseVideo()
    { return reverseVideo_; }

    public synchronized boolean getScroll()
    { return scroll_; }

    public synchronized int getTab()
    { return tab_; }

    public int getTileWidth()
    { return tileWidth_; }

    public int getTileHeight()
    { return tileHeight_; }

    public synchronized int getXOffset()
    { return xOffset_; }

    public synchronized int getYOffset()
    { return yOffset_; }

    public synchronized int getXCursor()
    { return xCursor_; }

    public static synchronized int getYCursor()
    { return yCursor_; }

    public synchronized void gotoxy(int x, int y)
    {
        xCursor_ = x;
        yCursor_ = y;
    }

    public synchronized void print(String s)
    {
        print(null, null, s);
    }

    public synchronized void print(Color bg, Color fg, String s)
    {
        for(int i = 0, len = s.length(); i < len; ++i) {
            print(bg, fg, s.charAt(i) );
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public synchronized void print(char c)
    {
        print(null, null, c);
    }

    public synchronized void print(Color bg, Color fg, char c)
    {
        if( escapeMode_ == ESC_NORMAL ) {
            switch(c) {
                case 7:     //  7 = BEL, bell
                    bell();
                    break;
                case '\b':  //  8 = BS, backspace
                    --xCursor_;
                    break;
                case '\t':  //  9 = HT, tab
                    xCursor_ = ((xCursor_ + tab_) / tab_) * tab_;
                    break;
                case '\n':  // 10 = LF, newline
                    xCursor_ = 0;
                    ++yCursor_;
                    //flag set to allow printing of ">>" prompt 
                    isNew=true;
                    break;
                case 11:    // 11 = VT, vertical tab
                case '\f':  // 12 = FF, form feed
                    ++yCursor_;
                    break;
                case '\r':  // 13 = CR, ignored because Java's newline is \n
                    break;
                case 27:    // 27 = ESC, enters escape mode
                    escapeMode_ = ESC_ESCAPE;
                    break;
                case 127: { // 127 = DEL, right-delete
                    int yc = yCursor_;
                    TerminalLine line = line_[yc];
                    for(int x = xCursor_; x < WIDTH-1; ++x) {
                        line.setData(x, line.bgColor[x+1], line.fgColor[x+1],
                            line.data[x+1], line.effects[x+1] );
                    }
                    setData(WIDTH-1, yc, null, null, ' ');
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    if( c < 32 ) {
                        // unknown control character
                        bell();
                    } else {
                        setData(xCursor_, yCursor_, bg, fg, c);
                        ++xCursor_;
                    }
            }
        } else {
            escapeMode_ = doEscape(c);
        } 
        // wrap cursor
        if( xCursor_ < 0 ) {
            if( wrap_ ) {
                xCursor_ = WIDTH-1;
                --yCursor_;
            } else {
                xCursor_ = 0;
            }
        } else if( xCursor_ >= WIDTH ) {
            if( wrap_ ) {
                xCursor_ = 0;
                ++yCursor_;
            } else {
                xCursor_ = WIDTH-1;
            }
        }
        if( yCursor_ < 0 ) {
            if( scroll_ ) {
                scrollDown(0);
            }
            yCursor_ = 0;
        } else if( yCursor_ >= HEIGHT ) {
            if( scroll_ ) {
                scrollUp(0);
            }
            yCursor_ = HEIGHT-1;
        }
        //cool flags here to print ">>" prompt: 1. when there is new line and 2. when the isR flag has detected the end of printing  in the return event.
        if(isR){
            isNew=false;

        }
        if(isNew){
            isNew=false;
         print(DARK_GREY, YELLOW, ">>");

        }
    }

    public synchronized void scrollDown(int topline)
    {
        // scroll down, exposing a blank line at top
        // don't waste the existing array, recycle it.
        TerminalLine line0 = line_[HEIGHT-1];
        // move all lines down
        for(int y = HEIGHT-1; y > topline; --y) {
            line_[y] = line_[y-1];
        }
        // put it at the top
        line_[topline] = line0;
        clearLine(topline);
    }

    public synchronized void scrollUp(int topline)
    {
        // scroll up, exposing a blank line at bottom
        // don't waste the existing array, recycle it.
        TerminalLine line0 = line_[topline];
        // move all lines up
        for(int y = topline; y < HEIGHT-1; ++y) {
            line_[y] = line_[y+1];
        }
        // put it at the end
        line_[HEIGHT-1] = line0;
        clearLine(HEIGHT-1);
    }

    private int doEscape(char c)
    {
        switch(escapeMode_) {
            case ESC_NORMAL:
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            case ESC_ESCAPE:
                // handled below
                break;
            case ESC_POS_Y:
                escapeHold_ = Math.max(0, Math.min(HEIGHT-1, (int)(c - 32)));
                return ESC_POS_X;
            case ESC_POS_X:
                yCursor_ = escapeHold_;
                xCursor_ = Math.max(0, Math.min(WIDTH-1, (int)(c - 32)));
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case ESC_FGCOLOR:
                setForeground( getColor( (int)c ) );
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case ESC_BGCOLOR:
                setBackground( getColor( (int)c ) );
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown escape mode "+escapeMode_);
        }

        switch(c) {
            case 24:        // 24 = CAN, cancel escape
            case 26:        // 26 = SUB, cancel escape
            case 27:        // 27 = ESC, cancel escape
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'A':       // Cursor Up
                if( yCursor_ > 0 ) {
                    --yCursor_;
                }
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'B':       // Cursor Down
                if( yCursor_ < HEIGHT-1 ) {
                    ++yCursor_;
                }
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'C':       // Cursor Forward
                if( xCursor_ < WIDTH-1 ) {
                    ++xCursor_;
                }
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'D':       // Cursor Backward
                if( xCursor_ > 0 ) {
                    --xCursor_;
                }
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'E':       // Clear Screen, Home Cursor
                clearScreen();
                xCursor_ = 0;
                yCursor_ = 0;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'H':       // Home Cursor
                xCursor_ = 0;
                yCursor_ = 0;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'I':       // Reverse Index
                --yCursor_;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'J':       // Erase to End of Page
                clearLine(yCursor_, xCursor_, WIDTH-1);
                for(int y = yCursor_+1; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
                    clearLine(y);
                }
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'K':       // Erase to End of Line
                clearLine(yCursor_, xCursor_, WIDTH-1);
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'L':       // Insert Line
                scrollDown(yCursor_);
                xCursor_ = 0;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'M':       // Delete Line
                scrollUp(yCursor_);
                xCursor_ = 0;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'N': {     // Delete Character
                int yc = yCursor_;
                TerminalLine line = line_[yc];
                for(int x = xCursor_; x < WIDTH-1; ++x) {
                    line.setData(x, line.bgColor[x+1], line.fgColor[x+1],
                        line.data[x+1], line.effects[x+1] );
                }
                setData(WIDTH-1, yc, null, null, ' ');
                break;
            }
            case 'Y':       // Position Cursor
                return ESC_POS_Y;
            case 'b':       // Set Foreground Color
                return ESC_FGCOLOR;
            case 'c':       // Set Background Color
                return ESC_BGCOLOR;
            case 'd': {     // Erase from Beginning of Display
                int xc = xCursor_, yc = yCursor_;
                clearLine(yc, 0, xc);
                for(int y = 0; y < yc; ++y) {
                    clearLine(y);
                }
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            }
            case 'j':       // Save Cursor Position
                xCursorSave_ = xCursor_;
                yCursorSave_ = yCursor_;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'k':       // Restore Cursor Position
                xCursor_ = xCursorSave_;
                yCursor_ = yCursorSave_;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'l':       // Erase Entire Line
                clearLine(yCursor_);
                xCursor_ = 0;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'm':       // Enable Cursor
                cursorVisible_ = true;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'n':       // Disable Cursor
                cursorVisible_ = false;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'o':       // Erase from Beginning of Line
                clearLine(yCursor_, 0, xCursor_);
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'p':       // Enable Reverse Video
                reverseVideo_ = true;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'q':       // Disable Reverse Video
                reverseVideo_ = false;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'r':       // Enable Underlining
                effects_ |= EFFECTS_UNDERLINE;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'u':       // Disable Underlining
                effects_ &= ~EFFECTS_UNDERLINE;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'v':       // Enable Wrapping
                wrap_ = true;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
            case 'w':       // Disable Wrapping
                wrap_ = false;
                return ESC_NORMAL;
        }
        // unknown escape code
        bell();
        return ESC_NORMAL;
    }

    public synchronized void println(String s)
    {
        println(null, null, s);
    }

    public synchronized void println(Color bg, Color fg, String s)
    {
        print(bg, fg, s);
        print(bg, fg, '\n');
        repaint();
    }

    public synchronized void setCursorVisible(boolean c)
    { cursorVisible_ = c; }

    public synchronized void setData(int x, int y, char c)
    {
        setData(x, y, null, null, c);
    }

    public synchronized void setData(int x, int y, Color bg, Color fg, char c)
    {
        setData(x, y, bg, fg, c, effects_);
    }

    public synchronized void setData(int x, int y, Color bg, Color fg, char c, byte effects)
    {
        if( bg == null ) {
            bg = getBackground();
        }
        if( fg == null ) {
            fg = getForeground();
        }
        if( reverseVideo_ ) {
            Color tmp = bg;
            bg = fg;
            fg = tmp;
        }
        TerminalLine line = line_[y];
        line.data[x] = c;
        line.bgColor[x] = bg;
        line.fgColor[x] = fg;
        line.effects[x] = effects;
    }

    public synchronized void setBgColor(int x, int y, Color b)
    {
        line_[y].bgColor[x] = b;
    }

    public synchronized void setEffects(int x, int y, byte e)
    {
        line_[y].effects[x] = e;
    }

    public synchronized void setFgColor(int x, int y, Color f)
    {
        line_[y].fgColor[x] = f;
    }

    public void setFont(Font font)
    {
        super.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fm = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getFontMetrics(font);
        tileWidth_ = fm.charWidth('W');
        tileHeight_ = fm.getHeight() - fm.getDescent();
        xOffset_ = 0;
        yOffset_ = -fm.getDescent();
        //System.out.println("tile "+tileWidth_+"x"+tileHeight_+", offset="+xOffset_+","+yOffset_);
    }

    public void setReverseVideo(boolean r)
    { reverseVideo_ = r; }

    public synchronized void setScroll(boolean s)
    { scroll_ = s; }

    public synchronized void setTab(int t)
    { tab_ = t; }

    public void setTileSize(int w, int h)
    {
        tileWidth_ = w;
        tileHeight_ = h;
        buffer_ = null;
    }

    public synchronized void setXOffset(int x)
    { xOffset_ = x; }

    public synchronized void setYOffset(int y)
    { yOffset_ = y; }

    public synchronized void setXCursor(int x)
    { xCursor_ = x; }

    public synchronized void setYCursor(int y)
    { yCursor_ = y; }

    public synchronized void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if( buffer_ != null ) {
            g.drawImage(buffer_, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void update(Graphics gg)
    {
        if( buffer_ == null ) {
            Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
            buffer_ = createImage(d.width, d.height);
            if( buffer_ == null ) {
                repaint(100L); //wtf?
                return;
            }
        }

        Graphics g = buffer_.getGraphics();
        g.setFont( getFont() );
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        char[] cbuf = new char[1];  // for drawChars
        for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
            int sy = y * tileHeight_;
            TerminalLine line = line_[y];
            for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) {
                int sx = x * tileWidth_;
                // background
                g.setColor( line.bgColor[x] );
                g.fillRect(sx, sy, tileWidth_, tileHeight_);
                // character
                g.setColor( line.fgColor[x] );
                cbuf[0] = line.data[x];
                g.drawChars(cbuf, 0, 1, sx + xOffset_,
                        sy + fm.getAscent() + yOffset_);
                // effects
                if( (line.effects[x] & EFFECTS_UNDERLINE) != 0 ) {
                    g.drawLine(sx, sy+tileHeight_-1,
                            sx+tileWidth_-1, sy+tileHeight_-1);
                }
                // borders for testing
                //g.drawLine(sx, sy, sx+tileWidth_-1, sy);
                //g.drawLine(sx, sy, sx, sy+tileHeight_-1);
            }
        }
        if( cursorVisible_ ) {
            Color bg = getBgColor(xCursor_, yCursor_);
            if( bg == BLACK ) {
                bg = WHITE;
            }
            g.setXORMode(bg);
            g.fillRect(xCursor_ * tileWidth_, yCursor_ * tileHeight_,
                    tileWidth_, tileHeight_);
            g.setPaintMode();
        }

        paint(gg);
    }

    }
    class TerminalLine
    {
    public Color[] bgColor;
    public Color[] fgColor;
    public char[] data;
    public byte[] effects;

    public TerminalLine(int width)
    {
        bgColor = new Color[width];
        fgColor = new Color[width];
        data = new char[width];
        effects = new byte[width];
    }
    public void setData(int x, Color bg, Color fg, char c, byte e)
    {
        data[x] = c;
        bgColor[x] = bg;
        fgColor[x] = fg;
        effects[x] = e;
    }   
 }
```